# In spacetime time is a coordinate. Does it mean there is a single objective timeline for the Universe?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, coordinate-systems, time, universe

If every event can be defined with x, y, z, t coordinates - does it mean all events with the same t are composing the whole Universe at the moment t?

Comment: Your question is rather vague (what does "composing the whole Universe" mean?) but I imagine the answer is pretty clearly 'no' because different observers measure different $t$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the choice of coordinates is not absolute. In flat spacetime, if you and I are moving relative to each other, then our time axes are tilted relative to each other. A plane of constant t in your frame of reference will be a sloping slice through time in mine, with t increasing all along the slope in one direction and deceasing all along it in the other. In curved spacetime, the effects can be much more complicated. In short, the idea of 'now' only makes sense locally- you cannot extrapolate your 'now' over distance and expect it to agree exactly with mine if we are moving relative to each other. At everyday speeds and distances, the magnitude of the effect is negligible, which is why we don't notice it.

The effect is known as the relativity of simultaneity and it is the cause of other effects. Length contraction, for example, arises because you consider either end of a moving object at what you consider to be the same moment. In the rest frame of the object, however, they are two separate moments, and the tail of the object has moved in the period between them to catch up with the head, thus making the object seem shorter.

Even though it is impossible to allocate a common t coordinate to 'now' everywhere, that does not mean that there isn't a 'now' everywhere- it just means that different observers will need to use different coordinates to refer to it. There is a parallel with spatial dimensions. If you live in New York, say, you will consider the horizontal to be a plane tangential to the Earth in New York, whereas if I live in London, I will pick a plane tangential with the Earth there. Neither of us can use the same z coordinate to measure sea level, since sea level in New York will have negative z value in my frame and vice versa. That doesn't mean that there is not a well-defined sea level- it just means that different observers use different values of z to refer to it. You cannot extrapolate sea level in New York to any distance. Likewise with time.

Comment: So can we say there ARE objective x-y-z-t coordinates to every event - we just can't figure them out?

Comment: A better way to think of it is that events are objective, but how we choose to label them with x-y-z-t coordinates is arbitrary. It is not a case of 'figuring anything out'. A coordinate is just a label that identifies the position of an event relative to some set of axes. Once you've picked your set of axes you can label any event with them. However, there is no absolute aspect to it. Take the idea of 'up' for example and 'directly overhead'. Up means in the direction of increasing z, and directly overhead means sharing the same x-y coordinate...

Comment: ...if you and I use different coordinate systems, then what is 'up' for you might be 'across' for me, and so on. There is no absolute 'up' in the universe.

Comment: Thank you. Got something.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. Isaac Newton would probably have said yes. Now we know better.

A single stationary observer can assign an $(x,y,z,t)$ value to every event he observes (or at least a $\phi$ and $\theta$ angle value of what direction it is in, and may have ways of determining the distance away $r$).  But another observer in a different location will assign different values $(X,Y,Z,T)$ to the same events, and her coordinates may be different – particularly if she is moving with respect to the first observer.  Neither can claim that their coordinates are any more correct than the other. The universe is egalitarian in that respect.

Also, as far as events in the universe experiencing time together: the fastest signals of any kind, and thus cause and effect itself, travel at the speed of light, approximately 300,000 km/s, or 8 minutes from the Sun to Earth. We cannot know what is happening in any part of the universe more quickly than that. Thus many of the far-away galaxies we see in the night sky do not exist anymore. We are seeing their after-images or "echoes."